# How to get flat array of eager loading in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

this my eloquent query:

```
$data = Disciplines::where('type', '<>', 'Initiator')
                ->with(['discipline_boxes.assign.box' => function($query) {
                        $query->select('id');
                }])
                 ->get();

    return $data;
```

i want return only array of id's of box relation
e.g:[2,3,4,5]

Comment: Doesn't "->toArray()" work?

Comment: All u have in documentation. Just read and implement: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: do you have the inverse for all these relationships defined?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-flatten ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!
this worked for me!

```
$disciplines = new Disciplines();
            $results  = $disciplines->getAllBox_ID()->toArray();
            dd(array_flatten(array_pluck($results,'discipline_boxes.*.assign.box.id')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially if you have the inverse for this chain of relationships you could get this information from the `Box` end (making name assumptions here):

```
Box::whereHas('assign.discipline_box.discipline', function ($q) {
    $q->where('type', '<>', 'Initiator');
})->pluck('id');
```